# How to get value of a class's array in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class `Payment_Type` with two fields `id` and `value`.

```
public class Payment_Type
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string value { get; set; }
  public Payment_Type(int p, string p_2)
  {
    this.id = p;
    this.value = p_2;
  }
  public static Payment_Type[] PaymentTypeList()
  {
     Payment_Type[] pay = new Payment_Type[4];
     pay[0] = new Payment_Type(1, "Cheque");
     pay[1] = new Payment_Type(2, "Demand Draft");
     pay[2] = new Payment_Type(3, "Cash");
     pay[3] = new Payment_Type(4, "Other");
     return pay;
   }
}
```

I want `value` of `id` 2. I tried following code but it's not working.

```
Byte Payment_Type_Id = 2
string val = Payment_Type.PaymentTypeList().GetValue(Payment_Type_Id).ToString();
```

It is giving me result as **namespace of Payment_Type class** i.e. `CRMEvent.Models.CRM.BLogic.Payment_Type`.

Help me I don't know what's wrong with it. I don't have deep knowledge of MVC.

Comment: What are you attempting to do here? Find something in the array with the specified ID, or get at the thing with the specified index in the array?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "It is giving me namespace of Payment_Type class.". This doesn't look like an error message that I recognise...

Comment: added in my question. see it

Comment: @MatthewWatson, when I pass 2 I should receive value as "Demand Draft"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Byte Payment_Type_Id = 2; // <- int will be better here
String val = Payment_Type.PaymentTypeList()[Payment_Type_Id].value.ToString();
```

Comment: @ProgrammerIT: The `-1` is why it is not best to rely on the index of an array for a lookup when that isn't technically what you are looking up.

Comment: @Chris, Yeh I know and that's why I still needed to find answer by Id of Payment_Type.

Comment: It would be nice if You;Dmitry Bychenko; HELP me to get value by Payment_Type class's ID

Comment: @ProgrammerIT: I assume you've seen my answer where I show how to make a dictionary that allows you to lookup the object based on the ID?

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ:

```
int paymentTypeId = 2;
var paymentType = Payment_Type.PaymentTypeList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == paymentTypeId);
if (paymentType == null)
{
    // no value with id=2 was found in the array
}
else
{
    // you could use the paymentType.value here
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit ambiguous what the OP wants to do, but this seems plausible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that `Payment_Type.PaymentTypeList().GetValue(Payment_Type_Id)` returns an object of type `Payment_Type`. When you call the `ToString` method on this it is using the base Object definition which just displays the object type.

```
Payment_Type.PaymentTypeList().GetValue(Payment_Type_Id).Value
```

This will get the string value of the selected item in the array.

You may want to look at different ways of accessing the item in the array though. I'd personally prefer to use a dictionary (since this kind of lookup is exactly what it is for) which would mean that if your items for some reason ever had gaps in the indexes you wouldn't have issues with the lookup.

```
public static Dictionary<int, Payment_Type> PaymentTypeList()
{
    var pay = new Dictionary<int, Payment_Type>();
    pay.Add(1, new Payment_Type(1, "Cheque"));
    pay.Add(2, new Payment_Type(2, "Demand Draft"));
    pay.Add(3, new Payment_Type(3, "Cash"));
    pay.Add(4, new Payment_Type(4, "Other"));
    return pay;
}
```

Then you can access what you want using:

```
Byte Payment_Type_Id = 3;
string val = Payment_Type.PaymentTypeList()[Payment_Type_Id].value;
```

This assumes that the id provided will always be in the list. If not you will need to do some checks to avoid exceptions.